# Get all the dates of the month from Day of week

Tags: c#, date

Is there any way to get all the occuring date for the particular day of the specified month and year..

For example:- If I have Day **Thursday** then I need all the dates of December 2016. Then collection should contain dates 1/12/2016, 8/12/2016, 15/12/2016, 22/12/2016, 29/12/2016.

Comment: have you trued anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to get the list of dates of the month based on day of a particular year like

```
public static List<DateTime> GetDates(int year, int month,string day)
    {
       return Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))
            .Where(d=>new DateTime(year, month, d).ToString("dddd").Equals(day))            
           .Select(d => new DateTime(year, month, d)).ToList(); 
    }
```

Now call this function like

```
var dates=GetDates(2016,12,"Thursday");
    foreach(var d in dates){
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
    }
```

*Output will be*

> 12/1/2016 12:00:00 AM
>
> 12/8/2016 12:00:00 AM
>
> 12/15/2016 12:00:00 AM
>
> 12/22/2016 12:00:00 AM
>
> 12/29/2016 12:00:00 AM

Now you have complete list of dates based on a day. You can further use it based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime decFirst = new DateTime(2016, 12, 1);
int offset = (int)decFirst.DayOfWeek;
DateTime decThursday = decFirst.AddDays(offset);
```

Now you have the first Thursday of December, you should be able to do the rest.

Comment: But If I have parameter value Monday then I need all the date which come in monday of Dec, 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Long form version...

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DateTime> Thursdays = DaysOfMonth(2016, 12, DayOfWeek.Thursday);
        foreach(DateTime dt in Thursdays)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
        }   
    }

    public static List<DateTime> DaysOfMonth(int year, int month, DayOfWeek day)
    {
        List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month); i++)
        {
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, i);
            if (dt.DayOfWeek == day)
            {
                dates.Add(dt);
            }
        }
        return dates;
    }
```