# What is the best way to make a DropDown list of Thursdays in C#?

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I am new to C# and would like to make a dropdown list containing all Thursday Dates?

I currently have an SQL table with all of these dates, but would rather have them generated in a function and used to populate a dropdown.

Any examples of best approach to this?

**Update:** I ended up using a calendar bootstrap-datepicker and disabled all days except Thursday’s. This gave me the current month Thursday’s and solved my issue.

Comment: What means _all_? You want all from birth of universe until end?

Comment: Yeah sounds like you are about to generate an infinite loop. Though it could work with lazy load.

Comment: How would you as a human do it? why not start by coding it in some way and seeing how this fairs? thursdays since year 0 ? future thursdays? next months thursdays?

Comment: You could probably tweak this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210598/get-all-the-dates-of-the-month-from-day-of-week

Comment: Offload complexity to the user - hard code adding 'Next' to Thursday n times.

Comment: Needed is all Thursdays within the current year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like that where you hard code the first Thursday you want to display, and then set how many Thursdays you want.

```
        var list = new List<DateTime>();
        DateTime firstThursday = new DateTime(2018,02,20);
        var numberOfThursdayWanted = 1000;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThursdayWanted; ++i)
        {
            list.Add(firstThursday.AddDays(i*7));
        }

        return list;
```

Comment: Nice answer, simple and helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to generate a list of "all":

```
DateTime firstThursday = DateTime.MinValue.AddDays(Enumerable.Range(0, 7).First(d => DateTime.MinValue.AddDays(d).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday));
int weeks = (int)Math.Ceiling((DateTime.MaxValue - firstThursday).Days / 7.0);
var allThursdays = Enumerable.Range(0, weeks).Select(d => firstThursday.AddDays(d * 7));
```

Note that `allThursdays` is just the LINQ query. If doesn't make sense to store all `DateTimes` in a collection. But maybe you want only those between a specific timespan, f.e.:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-10);
DateTime end = DateTime.Today.AddYears(10);
DateTime[] allThursDaysInLast10YearsUntilNext10Years = allThursdays
  .Where(d => d >= start && d <= end)
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: Does this even work? pretty sure DateTime will run out of days before int reaches MaxValue

Comment: I have the same fear. Is DateTime.MaxValue > (7 * int.MaxValue) days + DateTime.MinValue?

Comment: @user6144226: it does now with the `weeks` calculation

Comment: Seems so, there might be a one off error somewhere since the last Thursday came out as 12/23/9999 and I do think it could fit 12/30/9999 - but doubt this will be relevant in 7000 thousand years. (Don't even get me started on FirstDayOfWeek). Still good answer and the comment is about int's range is no longer relevant.

Comment: @user6144226: for what it's worth, now it should get "all"

Answer (score 1):

First you need to somehow narrow your results. For example by year, or by count as Dimitri suggests.

For that you can check this answer: [Create an array or List of all dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738748/create-an-array-or-list-of-all-dates-between-two-dates)

Once you have your `IEnumerable<DateTime>` you just have to use LINQ to filter the thurdays as follows:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> allDateTimes = null; //change this for whatever range you need
IEnumerable<DateTime> onlyThursdays = allDateTimes.Where(d => d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday);
```